# Why does this script add a question mark?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, iframe

I'm building a url shortening service but I noticed that this redirection script adds a question mark to the end of every url. http://tinyurl.com/j0t9 becomes http://tinyurl.com/j0t9? How come?

```
<script>
  function go(){
    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML='<form target="_parent" action="http://tinyurl.com/j0t9"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit()
  }    
</script>
<iframe onload="window.setTimeout('go()', 99)" src="about:blank" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's an easy one: You submit a GET request, and the browser adds the ? between URL and query string - even if the query string is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting a form using the (default) GET method. The data in the form (all none of it) is appended to the URI in a query string (the start of which is marked by a `?` character).